# $G$-Graded vector spaces and Yetter cohomology

Tags: category-theory, group-cohomology, monoidal-categories, fusion-categories

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203060) article, the following claims are made:

- The Yetter cohomology of $G$-graded $k$-vector spaces, for $G$ a finite group and $k$ algebraically closed, is given by group cohomology of $G$ with values in (the unit group of) $k$. (Example 7.2)
- The Yetter cohomology of a multi-fusion category vanishes. (Theorem 2.27)

It seems to me that these two statements are in direct contradiction. Clearly for finite $G$, the category of $G$-graded vector spaces is multifusion, since it is in particular fusion. But clearly, group cohomology doesn't vanish.

What's the resolution to this paradox?

Comment: Group cohomology does vanish if $k$ has characteristic not dividing the order of $G$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: The authors are a bit imprecise in what they mean by "group cohomology with values in $k$", it seems. In fact they must mean "group cohomology with values in the group of invertible elements of (the multiplicative group of) $k$", and not "group cohomology with values in the additive group of $k$". It's possible to check this when verifying that (the associators of) $G$-graded vector spaces are given up to equivalence by an element of $H^3(G,k^*)$.

Comment: So therefore it can be that the cohomology of $G$-graded $k$-vector spaces is nontrivial, since $H^3(G,k^*)$ can be nontrivial, while $k$ has still characteristic 0. This doesn't resolve the paradox, though...

Comment: As far as I can tell, in Example 7.2 they really mean the group cohomology with values in $k$. It is relevant that in that example they explicitly say that $k$ can be any characteristic. In Theorem 2.27, as in most of the paper, $k$ has characteristic zero. The distinction here is between first-order deformations of associators vs. associators themselves.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, oh, that might be the solution. Following http://etale.site/livetex/fusion.pdf, associators on $G$-graded $k$-vector spaces are given by a 3-cocycle with values in $k^*$, and they remark that the cocycles form a finite group. (There is no mention whether coboundaries give equivalences of categories, I think, but I believe it's true..?) So are you saying that cohomology in $k^*$ has a _"tangent''_ cohomology with values in $k^*$ which classifies smooth deformations of the cocycles? And saying that it's zero is the same as saying that cohomology in $k^*$ is discrete? (i.p. finite?)

Comment: On rereading the mentioned writeup, they actually say explicitly that $G$-graded vector spaces are given up to equivalence by $H^3(G,k^*)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qiaochu Yuan has brought me to the solution of the paradox, I believe.

Consider the category of finite dimensional $G$-graded $k$-vector spaces. It is a $k$-linear, semisimple category with finitely many simple objects, which correspond to the elements of the group. Call them $k_g, g \in G$. Their tensor product is then $k_{g_1} \otimes k_{g_2} = k_{g_1 g_2}$.

To choose an associator for the whole category, it suffices to define it on the simple objects. This means we have isomorphisms $\alpha_{g_1,g_2,g_3}\colon (k_{g_1} \otimes k_{g_2}) \otimes k_{g_3} \to k_{g_1} \otimes (k_{g_2} \otimes k_{g_3})$ satisfying the pentagon axiom. Since $k_{g_1 g_2 g_3}$ is a simple object, these correspond to invertible numbers in $k$ which we will call $\omega(g_1,g_2,g_3)$, and the pentagon axiom turns out to be the multiplicative cocycle condition:

$$ \omega(g_1, g_2, g_3) \omega(g_1, g_2 g_3, g_4) \omega(g_2, g_3, g_4) = \omega(g_1 g_2, g_3, g_4) \omega(g_1, g_2, g_3 g_4) $$

Furthermore, a monoidal equivalence between two copies of the same category with different associators is given by (an outer automorphism of $G$ and) a coboundary between the two cocycles, so indeed any category of $G$-graded vector spaces is given by a class in $H^3(G,k^*)$ (divided by outer automorphisms (since inner automorphisms don't touch cohomology)).

Now let us deform the associator. Replace $k$ by $k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$. An associator is now given by $\omega(g_1, g_2, g_3) + \varepsilon \omega'(g_1, g_2, g_3)$, where $\omega$ satisfies the cocycle condition as before, and $\omega'$ satisfies the *additive* cocycle condition:

$$ \omega'(g_1, g_2, g_3) + \omega'(g_1, g_2 g_3, g_4) + \omega'(g_2, g_3, g_4) = \omega'(g_1 g_2, g_3, g_4) + \omega'(g_1, g_2, g_3 g_4) $$

It is, in a sense, the derivative of the multiplicative cocycle condition.

Up to equivalence of categories, we have in particular $[\omega] \in H^3(G, k^*)$ and $[\omega'] \in H^3(G, k)$, in the latter considering the underlying additive group of $k$. $H^3(G, k)$ classifies in which directions we can "continuously deform" the associator.

Now for $k$ having characteristic 0 (or in general, as Qiaochu says, if the characteristic of $k$ doesn't divide the order of the group), $H^3(G,k) = 0$, which means that we cannot deform the associator at all. In particular, there are only finitely many different possible associators. This is a special case of a statement called "Ocneanu rigidity".

Comment: Yes, this is right as far as I know.